# Code wont work because my root is always NULL

Tags: c

I have to do a simple Binary Search Tree, every single function works fine but it won't print what it has to print because my root stays NULL, I can't for the life of me fix this.

```
struct student;
typedef struct student *position;
typedef struct student{

    char ime[128];
    char prezime[128];
    int brBod;
    float relbrBod;
    position Left;
    position Right;

}stud;

int InorderPrint(position);
int ReadFromFile(position);
position Insert(char*,char*,int,position);

int main(){

    position root = NULL;

    if(ReadFromFile(root)==ERROR)
        {   
            printf("Greska u RFF");
            return ERROR;
    }

    InorderPrint(root);

    return SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Can you also post the ReadFromFile function ?

Comment: you don't show any code that changes `root` so why would you expect it to change?

Comment: The point you're missing is that you're passing root into ReadFromFile by value, not by reference. To pass by reference you can pass a pointer to it, or you could have ReadFromFile return you a new root.